# jquery on click event that call a named function

Tags: jquery, event-handling

I have a jQuery `onClick` handler, writed with an anonymous function like that:

```
$("#selector").on("click" function(){
    // do something
})
```

I would generalize the anonymous function extracting the logic in a named function, that drive me to something like:

```
$("#selector").on("click" namedFunction())

function namedFunction(){
    // do something
}
```

To me seemed a good solution. But there's a drawback since the `namedFunction` is executed as soon script is loaded. [**Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/EgYxg/) you can test the bad behaviour.

Answer (score 17):

Just pass the `reference` of that function itself.

Try,

```
$("#selector").on("click", namedFunction);
```

Comment: And what if I need to send parameters to that function?

Comment: The parameters are sent by default; in this case for example, the event is sent as a parameter to namedFunction

Comment: @BAD_SEED to send parameters [look at here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61725426/6791254)

Answer (score 5):

You don't need the `()` for your function here:

```
$("#selector").on("click", namedFunction)
```

Answer (score 3):

Or a shorter version

```
$("#selector").click(namedFunction);
```

Answer (score 2):

To pass custom parameters to `namedFunction` use:

```
$("#selector").on("click", null, {param1: param1}, namedFunction);


namedFunction(event) { console.log(event.data.param1); }
```

Answer (score 1):

try like

```
function namedFunction(){
alert("Hello world!")
}
$("#clickTester").on('click', namedFunction)
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/EgYxg/1/)

Answer (score 1):

#### Named function[view [*jsFiddle*](http://jsfiddle.net/EgYxg/8/)]

```
Function namedFunction () {
    alert("Hello world!");
}
$("#clickTester").on('click', namedFunction);
```

---

#### Anonymous function [view [*jsFiddle*](http://jsfiddle.net/EgYxg/2/)]

```
$("#clickTester").click(function(){
   alert("Hello world!");
});
```